# Wireless card is turned off by default when Windows starts. How to change this?

Tags: wireless-networking, netbook

I have a netbook (Siragon, local brand) and whenever I power it up and go into the OS (either XP or 7) the wireless card is off by default.

It's not really a big issue; I just tap the keys and it turns on but the netbook is mainly for my mom to use, so it would be better if the W-card just turns on whenever I power up.

Are there any registry changes, group policies, security policies etc that will make this possible?

Comment: The card is disabled or what? If you could explain the steps you take to enable it that would be beneficial.

Comment: Is turned off. I press the function key (Fn) + F2 to turned it on.

Answer (score 1):

Check the BIOS for a setting to enable or disable it by default on start up. You access the BIOS when you first turn the computer on. Typically you press the F2 or F10 key (there should be in structions on the screen).

Answer (score 1):

In control panel look for the term wireless.  Else search it. Perhaps Network Adapters.  Or go to the device manager.  There under network adapters look for your wireless device...most likely it will NOT have ethernet in it, that will be a seperate device.

From there go to power management.  YOu want to be sure that you read the option ... mine said to check the top box if I wanted the computer to be able to turn off wireless to save power.

You might also have to do something with the power management options creating an energy plan that uses high-performance settings.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Device Manager
2. Under Adapters, double-click to open wireless adapter
3. Disable it

When you need it again, enable it.